# boot with irqpoll

Tags: boot, grub2

I'm getting an IRQ 19 Error Nobody Cared.

Google tells me to boot with `irqpoll`, but I'm not sure how to do this.

I'm on Ubuntu 8.04.4 LTS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using Grub Legacy (and not Grub2) :

Edit the `/boot/grub/menu.lst` file.

Search for the relevant menu entry at the end of the file, it looks like that :

```
title Ubuntu 8.04, kernel 2.6.24-16-generic
root (hd0,0)
kernel /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.24-16-generic root=UUID=c8acb88f-fb57-4ebc-ba34-56de426a34f0 ro quiet splash
initrd /boot/initrd.img-2.6.24-16-generic
quiet
```

Add the `irqpoll` kernel option at the end of the third line :

```
kernel /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.24-16-generic root=UUID=c8acb88f-fb57-4ebc-ba34-56de426a34f0 ro quiet splash irqpoll
```

Save the file and reboot your computer.